# UIPageViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hi am following a tutorial on UIPageViewController to generate a gallery of pictures in my project http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/easy-steps-to-implement-uipageviewcontroller-in-swift even download the demo and it works but in my if I get an error and the application falls.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[image]

at next my code.

PageContentViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class PageContentViewController: UIPageViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


    var pageIndex: Int = 0
    var strTitle: String!
    var strPhotoName: String!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: strPhotoName)
        lblTitle.text = strTitle

    }
}
```

ViewController2.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    var arrPageTitle: NSArray = NSArray()
    var arrPagePhoto: NSArray = NSArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arrPageTitle = ["This is The App Guruz", "This is Table Tennis 3D", "This is Hide Secrets"];
        arrPagePhoto = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"];

        self.dataSource = self

        self.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex(0)] as [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK:- UIPageViewControllerDataSource Methods

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let pageContent: PageContentViewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController

        var index = pageContent.pageIndex

        if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound))
        {
            return nil
        }

        index -= 1;
        return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let pageContent: PageContentViewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController

        var index = pageContent.pageIndex

        if (index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil;
        }

        index += 1;
        if (index == arrPageTitle.count)
        {
            return nil;
        }
        return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    // MARK:- Other Methods
    func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> PageContentViewController
    {
        // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController

        pageContentViewController.strTitle = "\(arrPageTitle[index])"
        pageContentViewController.strPhotoName = "\(arrPagePhoto[index])"
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index

        return pageContentViewController
    }



}
```

Comment: `strPhotoName` is `nil` because you haven't set it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Joakin is right, you are forcing the unwrap of an optional value, you need to either initialize your values when you declare them or treat them as optionals and unwrap them as you need them.

Try this:

```
var strTitle: String?
var strPhotoName: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let photoName = strPhotoName {
     imageView.image = UIImage(named: photoName)
    }

    if let title = strTitle {
     lblTitle.text = title
    }
}
```

Then, somewhere in your code you need to specify the name of the image (make sure the image exists in your project) and the name of the title. If you dont specify them, the updated lines of code will not get executed.

Read more about optional values [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Comment: I try what are you saying but i got the same error. May be the communication between the PageContentViewController and the ViewController2?

Comment: Can you post the updated error after you change the code? The error in your question is directly related to the forced unwrapping of an optional value. can you confirm that the image you are using has the correct name and exist in the project?

Comment: ![Image](http://subefotos.com/ver/?b15b29a8dec79c51bbd8bbddb0ee0f65o.png).

![Image2](http://subefotos.com/ver/?a926e699747106523208af14680a1b9co.png).

Comment: I see, you are technically still doing the same as before. Let me explain, In swift, when you declare a variable or constant, you need to either specify its value, or make it an optional. An optional is a variable that may, or may not have a value. When you declare your variables as var strTitle: String! (with a ! at the end) you are declaring  it as an optional, and unwrapping it straight away, but the variable has no value, so when its used it fails (its nil), you need to change the ! for ?, then add a value to them before you use them, your error is here http://imgur.com/N1u94g7.

Comment: my last doubt i follow an example about this and i download the test code and i try and it works with the same variable declaration why is happening that?

Comment: I checked the tutorial, he uses a method called getViewControllerAtIndex where he adds the value for the variables, so when the view is loaded those values are set, and its not nil. This is done in the very last step of the tutorial, at 6.4.1

Comment: well i will keep working to solve this thanks for the info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113474/discussion-between-daniel-ormeno-and-nicolas-rudisky).

Answer (score 1):

```
var strPhotoName: String!
```

It is literally nil. You will need to assign it a image name.
Let's say your image is called cloudsImage.png

You would set your var strPhotoName like this in viewDidLoad if you want.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    strPhotoName = "cloudsImage.png"
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: strPhotoName)
    lblTitle.text = strTitle

}
```

Comment: I try what you said but i got the same error, may be in the comunication between the PageContentViewController and the ViewController2?

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class PageContentViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


    var pageIndex: Int = 0
    var strTitle: String!
    var strPhotoName: String!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: strPhotoName)
        lblTitle.text = strTitle

    }
}
```

the main error was that the class of the page was wrong now the problem is solved.